# Beta regression - simultaneously tracking all components so that proportions sum to 1.0

Tags: r, beta-regression, dirichlet-regression

I am trying to fit a beta regression model in R with the outcome variable representing proportions, so that the model accounts for all of the constituents of the whole fraction. I am unclear how to keep track of multiple constituents at once. I have looked at a lot of different examples (using, for example, the `betareg` or `glmmTMB` packages), but couldn't quite find something that deals with the issue. The examples I have just focus on a single constituent among the proportions. It is also relevant that it should account for the fact that they need to sum to 1.0, although I realise that this over-specifies the problem, because the final proportion is determined by the sum of the others.

Here's a synthetic dataset to try to illustrate what I am *trying* to do here:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(betareg)
library(glmmTMB)
set.seed(15)

df <- expand.grid(a = 1:5,b = 1:6,c=1:7)
n <- nrow(df)
## constituents of the sum
df$A <- sin(df$a) + 1 + runif(n)
df$B <- cos(df$b) + 1 + runif(n)
df$C <- log(df$c) + runif(n)
## proportions of the sum
df$pA <- with(df,A/(A+B+C))
df$pB <- with(df,B/(A+B+C))
df$pC <- with(df,C/(A+B+C))
## factor levels to represent which constituent was being sampled
LETS <- LETTERS[1:3]
df_reshaped <- rbind(cbind(rename(df[,c(1:3,7)], proportion = pA),
                           component = factor(rep('A',n),levels = LETS)),
                     cbind(rename(df[,c(1:3,8)], proportion = pB),
                           component = factor(rep('B',n),levels = LETS)),
                     cbind(rename(df[,c(1:3,9)], proportion = pC),
                           component = factor(rep('C',n),levels = LETS)))
## represent the predictors as categorical variables
df_reshaped$a <- factor(df_reshaped$a)
df_reshaped$b <- factor(df_reshaped$b)
df_reshaped$c <- factor(df_reshaped$c)

str(df_reshaped)
## output:
## 'data.frame':        630 obs. of  5 variables:
##  $ a         : Factor w/ 5 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 ...
##  $ b         : Factor w/ 6 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...
##  $ c         : Factor w/ 7 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
##  $ proportion: num  0.459 0.489 0.42 0.282 0.119 ...
##  $ component : Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
head(df_reshaped)
## output:
##   a b c proportion component
## 1 1 1 1  0.4585355         A
## 2 2 1 1  0.4888762         A
## 3 3 1 1  0.4196652         A
## 4 4 1 1  0.2824253         A
## 5 5 1 1  0.1194853         A
## 6 1 2 1  0.6089280         A
tail(df_reshaped)
## output:
##     a b c proportion component
## 625 5 5 7  0.5939893         C
## 626 1 6 7  0.3491562         C
## 627 2 6 7  0.2814178         C
## 628 3 6 7  0.3306160         C
## 629 4 6 7  0.3385776         C
## 630 5 6 7  0.4702073         C

## this *does not* work (!!), but aims to capture the meaning of what I am after
mod1 <- betareg(proportion | component ~ a + b + c, data = df_reshaped)
## output:
## Error in betareg(proportion | component ~ a + b + c, data = df_reshaped) :
##   empty model

## this *does* run, but I don't think it represents what I am trying to achieve here
mod2 <- glmmTMB(proportion ~ a + b + c + (1 | component), data = df_reshaped, beta_family())
```

Neither of the model specifications above really capture what I am aiming to achieve.

**Edit**: Thanks to an insightful comment from @dimitriy, I was able to find the representation I was after. This uses Dirichlet regression, and was achieved using the `DirichletReg` package.

```r
library (DirichletReg)

## create 'factor' objects for these unordered categorical variables
df$fa <- factor(df$a)
df$fb <- factor(df$b)
df$fc <- factor(df$c)
df$Y <- DR_data(df[,c('pA','pB','pC')])

res1 <- DirichReg(Y ~ fa + fb + fc, data = df)
summary(res1)

## Just as a sanity-check, extract the coefficients, and compare them
## for what we might expect based on the construction of the data.
x1 = rowMeans(sapply(coef(res1),'[',2:5));      ## extract components for the 'A' factor
x2 = sin(2:5) - sin(1)                          ## contributions from the 'A' factor
y1 = rowMeans(sapply(coef(res1),'[',1:5 + 5));  ## extract components for the 'B' factor
y2 = cos(2:6) - cos(1)                          ## contributions from the 'B' factor
z1 = rowMeans(sapply(coef(res1),'[',1:6 + 10)); ## extract components for the 'C' factor
z2 = log(2:7)                                   ## contributions from the 'C' factor
cor(x1,x2) ## comparison for the 'A' factor (only 4 coefficients to account for)
## [1] 0.9774279
cor(y1,y2) ## comparison for the 'B' factor (5 coefficients to consider)
## [1] 0.9472137
cor(z1,z2) ## comparison for the 'C' factor (5 coefficients to consider)
## [1] 0.8884948
```

However, there is a trade-off. There don't appear to be many options for performing Dirichlet regression in R (there's also the `zoid` package - maybe others too). According to [Douma & Weedon, 2019][1], at the time when that review was conducted there were no R packages that could handle mixed-effects or zero-/one-inflated response variables.

[1]: Douma & Weedon (2019): Analysing continuous proportions in ecology and evolution: A practical introduction to beta and Dirichlet regression. Methods in Ecology and Evolution. Vol. 10, Iss. 9, pp. 1412-1430. https://doi.org/10.1111/2041-210X.13234

Comment: How do you wind up with the proportion values? If you can model the discrete events (maybe you can’t, but maybe you can), a multinomial accomplishes your goal of having the sum be one.

Comment: Have you thought about using Dirichlet regression?

Comment: @Dave - In response to the question in your comment ("How do you wind up with the proportion values?"), there are situations when we are interested in modelilng the fraction/proportion of a total (e.g., fraction of the total time spent doing one of several activities). 
Regarding the suggestion about the type of model, I'm not sure that the multinomial really covers it - you would normally fit a multinomial with a (nominal) categorical response variable as the outcome, but in this case we have proportions as the response variable in the dataset. Does that help clarify it?

Comment: @dimitriy - this was an excellent suggestion, and provides the answer I was after. Thank you!

Comment: @dimitriy - I'm satisfied with your suggestion. I can accept it if you can post it as an Answer (preferably in a more expanded form).

Comment: It's better to add answers as anwers, so that the question can be counted as answered. You can answer your question btw @nullglob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use maximum likelihood Dirichlet regression to model outcomes that are proportions in [0,1] that add up to one and covariates.

You can also try a quasi-maximum likelihood fractional multinomial logit model.

There are R and Stata packages for both, and maybe others that I am unaware of. I am unsure if either can accommodate mixed effects or zero-/one-inflated response variables off the shelf. I suggest that you elaborate more on that aspect of the problem in a new question.